# Quickbooks Online Api - Is there a way to get a list of all available custom fields for Invoice?

Tags: quickbooks-online

I have been going through the Intuit Developer documentation for about 10 hours trying to find a way to get a list of invoice "custom fields" that have been set up for a Quickbooks Online Company file.  I'm not sure if it is even possible.  It if is, can anyone point me to some code, documentation, or anything that could possibly help me get such a list.  Is it available somehow through the QueryService?  Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: were you able to find out how to do this? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: Yes.  I am including now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets custom fields:

```
public static List<Preferences> getCustomFields()
    {
        ServiceContext serviceContext = getServiceContext();
        QueryService<Preferences> preferencesQueryService = new QueryService<Preferences>(serviceContext);
        return preferencesQueryService.ExecuteIdsQuery("Select * FROM Preferences").ToList<Preferences>();
    }
List<Preferences> prefs = RestHelper.getCustomFields();
            List<CustomFieldDefinition> cusfieldDefs = prefs[0].SalesFormsPrefs.CustomField.ToList() as List<CustomFieldDefinition>;
            List<StringTypeCustomFieldDefinition> customFields = cusfieldDefs.OfType<StringTypeCustomFieldDefinition>().ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

I started here: [API Reference](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/account).

As well, to grab all of the fields with values I made a query to the Quickbooks record, with a SELECT * statement.  That brings everything back, with data.